# Is it possible to 301 redirect a domain but still send 404 headers when appropriate?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am using `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ http://newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` to redirect users from one site to another. The root exception in this instance is deliberate; that is, I want visitors to oldsite.com to not be redirected, but visitors to oldsite.com/anypage to be redirected to newsite.com/anypage.

However, when someone manually types in oldsite.com/qwerty (a non-existing page), they (and presumably any search engine) get a 301 redirect and not a 404 error. Is there a rule-based way to avoid this behaviour or do I need to change my .htaccess so that there are individual 301 redirects listed (so that anything else will then give the desired 404 result)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For simplicity I will refer to "Google" here, but it applies to any search engine.*

This is basically a non-issue. The 301 redirects are mostly there to keep your Google ranking from the old domain on the new domain and keep bookmarks valid. If a page existed on the old domain, it should still exist on the new domain.

If someone types a non-existing page on the old domain, the user will see the 404 message on the new domain, but that is okay. Google does not crawl that url. In fact any automated crawler should never encounter that url, so semantics about getting a 301 redirect before a 404 status code does not really apply.

There are two things to look out for:

- You had a page on the old domain that now exists under a different name on the new domain. You should add a manual exception for this:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^mypage$ https://newsite.com/new-page-with-something-fancy [R=301,L]
  ```
- You had a page on the old domain that no longer exists on the new domain. You should manually add an exception that returns the "Gone" status code

  ```
  RewriteRule ^i-no-longer-exist$ - [G,L]
  ```

There does not really exist a way of checking the status code of the redirected page, unless you go into the land of rewriting to a script that uses something like curl to check the other site, or use something like a proxy. Both are awfully inefficient and hurt your site's ranking more than it could ever gain.

Comment: Even though I didn't mention search engines in my question, that is actually what was on my mind (Google not encountering 404s for pages that don't exist) when I posed the question. Bearing what you said in mind, I will leave the 301 redirects as they are. (None of the page addresses have changed, aside from the domain itself.) Thank you!